# How can i make this custom Stepper?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make the Stepper with two circle (one inside other), linked to other circle, but that circle inside other is hard to do, i can i do it?

I try using this https://jsfiddle.net/dedi_wibisono17/c69e374r/2/  and change it to look like that i want to do, but i fail!

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 offset-md-2 block border">
    <div class="wrapper-progressBar">
      <ul class="progressBar">
        <li class="active">Beong Processed</li>
        <li class="active">Waiting for payment</li>
        <li>Paid</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


.wrapper-progressBar {
    width: 100%
}

.progressBar {
}

.progressBar li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

.progressBar li:before {
    content: " ";
    line-height: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto 10px;
    background-color: white
}

.progressBar li:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    top: 15px;
    left: -50%;
    z-index: -1;
}

.progressBar li:first-child:after {
    content: none;
}

.progressBar li.active {
    color: dodgerblue;
}

.progressBar li.active:before {
    border-color: dodgerblue;
    background-color: dodgerblue
}

.progressBar li.active + li:after {
    background-color: dodgerblue;
}
```

there was an error, the linked line with z-index=-1 it stay behind the section background, how can i put it in front ( i try change z-index but it not look well, it stay in front of the circle)

Comment: this is my custom stepper https://pasteboard.co/IgMVyBy.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you closer to what you're going for.

```
.wrapper-progressBar {
    width: 100%;
}

.progressBar {
}

.progressBar li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    color:white
}

.progressBar li:before {
    content: " ";
    line-height: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;       
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding:5px;
    margin: 15px auto 25px;
    background-color: white;

}

.progressBar li:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 94%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #19C1D5;
    top: 18px;
    left: -47%;   
}

.progressBar li:first-child:after {
    content: none;
}

.progressBar li.active:before {
  margin:0 auto 10px;
  border:15px solid #19C1D5;
}
```

The main changes were changing the margin of the `li:before` so it acts as a transparent border for the top and bottom, and changing `li.active:before` to revert the margin/add the border.